# CakePHP v2 named Model same as folder in webroot

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

This is on CakePHP version 2.  I had been following the blog guide to create a website and I wanted to add a model to store photos in the database.  I created a new Model called Photo with PhotosController.  What I didn't realize is that it would conflict with a folder called photos in my webroot.  When I generate a link to controller => photos, action => index, or even type in domain.com/photos it redirects to domain.com/app/webroot/photos.  While it used to show the files, I deleted the folder on the webroot because I wanted it to go to the index function of PhotosController.  Even with that folder gone, it keeps trying to go to that no matter what I've tried.

From the research I've done, I believe it has something to do with mod_rewrite.  Is there a way to tell it to forget that at one time there was a webroot folder named photos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use route 
Router::connect('/photo', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'index'));

Seems you face browser caching, check with private browsing chrome(ctrl+shift+N)

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of it, but it was just browser caching.  Tried on another browser and it gave me the correct page.  Thanks!